# After changing WebRTC LegacyAudioDeviceModel, IOS to android call connected... but not answer able

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am using WebRTC for audio call in my app. I am facing the following issue

Android App to Android App --> Call function --->Working Fine

iOS App to iOS App -->Call function --->Working Fine

Android App to iOS App -->Call function --->Not Working

In the below mentioned function, the "newState" always returning CHECKING state

```
@Override
    public void onIceConnectionState(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState newState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ICE= " + newState);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (newState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                    callType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (type.equals("audio")) {
                        callTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        startCountDown("answer");
                    } else {
                        updateVideoViews(true);
                    }
                } else if (newState == PeerConnectenter code hereion.IceConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    callType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    callType.setText(getString(R.string.poor_connection_connecting));
                    callTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (newState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.CLOSED) {

                } else {
                    callType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    callType.setText(getString(R.string.connecting));
                    callTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The Legacy file i am using is given below link
link: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/audio/LegacyAudioDeviceModule.java

Comment: can you share your code to create `PeerConnectionFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by codec, make sure you create `PeerConnectionFactory` in the right way:

```
final PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
final DefaultVideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(eglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);
final DefaultVideoDecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(eglBase.getEglBaseContext());
peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().setOptions(options).
                setVideoDecoderFactory(decoderFactory).
                setVideoEncoderFactory(encoderFactory).
                createPeerConnectionFactory();
```